# Query not returning results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have written the following query which returns some results which i originally required:

```
DECLARE @lastMonthDate VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @currentMonthDate VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(10)

SET @lastMonthDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-21'
SET @currentMonthDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()))+'-20'
SET @Year = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())

SELECT 
     DISTINCT 
     Comp_Name
     , comp_idnr 
     , oppo_date17_1sent
     ,datename(month, oppo_date17_1sent)
     , budg_tempDODate1
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), budg_do1_total) AS budg_do1_total
     , budg_paymentMethodM_R
     , Commissions.dbo.Simplicity_Paid.RestructureFeeActualDate
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),
                Commissions.dbo.Simplicity_Paid.RestructureFees) as RestructureFees
     , Commissions.dbo.Simplicity_Paid.RestructureFeeStatus
     , Channel.Chan_Description 

 FROM 
     Company
JOIN Commissions.dbo.Simplicity_Paid 
     on company.Comp_CompanyId = Commissions.dbo.Simplicity_Paid.CompanyID 
JOIN Opportunity 
     on Company.Comp_CompanyId = Opportunity.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId
JOIN Budget 
     on  Opportunity.Oppo_OpportunityId = Budget.budg_OpportunityId
JOIN Users 
     on company.Comp_PrimaryUserId = User_UserId
Join Channel 
     on User_PrimaryChannelId = Channel.Chan_ChannelId

WHERE 
     CONVERT(DATE, RestructureFeeActualDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @lastMonthDate) 
                                           AND CONVERT(DATE, @currentMonthDate) 
AND 
     User_FirstName = 'Joshua' 
AND 
     User_LastName = 'Niss' 
And 
     RestructureFeeStatus = 'Paid' 
AND 
     RestructureFees >= 900 
AND 
     Oppo_Deleted IS NULL
```

As projects go, requirements have now changed and I needed to add a little more SQL to my code to get my desired results. Problem is... I'm not getting what I need.

I am trying to add the following:

`AND comp_idnr NOT IN (SELECT ClientID FROM Commissions.dbo.AuditHistory)`

But for some or other reason, my query is not returning any results anymore. *You may be thinking, well that's because the ID is in the query.* BUT I can assure you it is **not**. I have manually checked the data and only find 1 record.

I have been trawling the internet for things like "Why would a *NOT IN* statement not be working", how else to do it etc.

`My attempts include: Joins (LEFT & RIGHT), Exists and Not exists, IN vs NOT IN`

I Remember someone once told me, the way you structure your `WHERE` clause would output different results. So this is my question I guess, *"How would I structure my where clause" ? Or do you guys see nothing wrong with that either and I should just carry on trying different things?*

Sorry if this is a crappy post, I just really have no idea what else to try. Is there any more information I can provide you with which would assist you in helping me?

**Just a quick EDIT:** The query does find the 1 record that is `IN` that subquery.

Comment: Are there null values in comp_idnr or ClientId?  Does it literally stop returning results as soon as you add the (Select.. not in ..)?

Comment: I would also be somewhat fearful of using distinct.  Rather use group by, where you can see what is being returned or duplicated.  Select distinct sometimes hides dragons...

Comment: @AnthonyHorne.. There are no `NULL` values that I am aware of... And yes, When I add that last condition, it goes from displaying 14 records to 0 records :(

Comment: If you add ClientID to the distinct list - what do you get?

Comment: what you mean by "BUT I can assure you it is not. I have manually checked the data and only find 1 record."? There is one record in Commissions.dbo.AuditHistory?

Comment: @Darka.. Sorry for the confusion, there are 618 records in `Commissions.dbo.AuditHistory` and from the original query (which returned 14 records) 13 are `NOT IN` there and 1 is `IN` that table.. So essentially, the New query I am trying to write should display those 13 records that are `NOT IN` that table

Comment: so you took this 14 records, placed into `IN` (of `Commissions.dbo.AuditHistory` table) and got 13 results? Or checked just by looking at it?

Comment: Negative. I'm just assuming... Those 14 records I had (ID's) I manually searched for each ID in the `618 IDs` and only found 1. So that lead me to believe I should be seeing 13 results returned. OR is there some other sorcery at play here that I am not aware of? :)

Comment: Maybe IDs are some varchar type and you don't see space :D

Comment: I added this `RTRIM(LTRIM(@String1))` to both `ClientID` & `comp_idnr` and still nothing? Anything else you would recommend? :)

Comment: so it is string after all (I thought it is integer). Maybe silly note but maybe it is related to different collation or something related? Also Notepad++ always helps to see if data are equal :) And just one more idea, what if you will join only this two tables ant this two columns (will be any matches)?

Comment: you touched a good point there... I really have no idea how that `COLLATE` function works, but I am using it on my one ID. `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` - but then again, not sure what else I can make this. This is the only one that is not giving me an error. haha

Comment: ... WHERE COl1 COLLATE ..lat... = col2 COLLATE ..lat...